# Can't Change AVSpeechSynthesisVoice Locale With iOS TTS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, locale, text-to-speech

Using *Xcode 7.2*, different deployment targets (e. g. 7.1 and 9.2) and different virtual devices (e. g. iPhone 6s plus and iPhone 5s) I am not able to switch the spoken TTS language. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance()

    func speak(locale: String, text: String) {
        if let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: locale) {
            myUtterance.voice = voice

            // I read that the delays might cure the issue,
            // but they don't. Language switching does not
            // work with or without this.
            myUtterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0.005
            myUtterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0.005

            // I read that an empty text cures the issue,
            // but is doesn't. Language switching does not
            // work with or without this.
            for t in [" ", text] {
                myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: t)
                synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
            }
        } else {
            debugPrint("bad voice")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        speak("de-DE", text: "Ich blicke auf einen blauen Himmel!")
        speak("en-US", text: "This is a text, which I like very much!")
    }
}
```

Both texts are read, but only in the device's standard language.

Furthermore I get the following error when I run the code:

```
2015-12-23 12:15:20.593 HFV[6993:964424] |AXSpeechAssetDownloader|error|   
ASAssetQuery error fetching results (for 
com.apple.MobileAsset.MacinTalkVoiceAssets) Error Domain=ASError Code=21 
"Unable to copy asset information" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy 
asset information}
```

Running the app on an iPhone 4 (not virtual, it's a real device with iOS 7.1.2) the app starts and this error does not occur, but the TTS doesn't work at all.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If I run the code above with a phone set to language "en_US" only the first text is pronounced incorrectly. If I append _speak("de-DE", text: "Ich blicke auf einen blauen Himmel!")_ after _speak("en-US", text: "This is a text, which I like very much!")_ everything is pronounced incorrectly. This is funny, isn't it?

Comment: Surprisingly the following code is a workaround: _speak("de-DE", text: "Ich blicke auf einen blauen Himmel!"); speak("de-DE", text: " "), speak("en-US", text: "This is a text, which I like very much!"); speak("en-US", text: " ")_